# Import a module from a relative path

Tags: python, relative-path, python-import

How do I import a Python module given its relative path?

For example, if `dirFoo` contains `Foo.py` and `dirBar`, and `dirBar` contains `Bar.py`, how do I import `Bar.py` into `Foo.py`?

Here's a visual representation:

```
dirFoo\
    Foo.py
    dirBar\
        Bar.py
```

`Foo` wishes to include `Bar`, but restructuring the folder hierarchy is not an option.

Comment: Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python, maybe?

Comment: Check my answer, it is the most complete so far, others are not working in special case, for example when you call the script from another directory or from another python script. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/python-import-a-module-from-a-folder/6098238#6098238

Comment: I had a similar problem and I found this and it works!! apt-get install python-profiler

Comment: Just in case somebody wants to do it statically and gets here (like I did :) you can also set up the PYTHONPATH environment variable

Comment: Better is to follow the instructions in Lib/site.py for each case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import the class within the same directory or sub directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory)

Answer (score 350, accepted):

Assuming that both your directories are real Python packages (do have the `__init__.py` file inside them), here is a safe solution for inclusion of modules relatively to the location of the script.

I assume that you want to do this, because you need to include a set of modules with your script. I use this in production in several products and works in many special scenarios like: scripts called from another directory or executed with python execute instead of opening a new interpreter.

```
 import os, sys, inspect
 # realpath() will make your script run, even if you symlink it :)
 cmd_folder = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.split(inspect.getfile( inspect.currentframe() ))[0]))
 if cmd_folder not in sys.path:
     sys.path.insert(0, cmd_folder)

 # Use this if you want to include modules from a subfolder
 cmd_subfolder = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.split(inspect.getfile( inspect.currentframe() ))[0],"subfolder")))
 if cmd_subfolder not in sys.path:
     sys.path.insert(0, cmd_subfolder)

 # Info:
 # cmd_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) # DO NOT USE __file__ !!!
 # __file__ fails if the script is called in different ways on Windows.
 # __file__ fails if someone does os.chdir() before.
 # sys.argv[0] also fails, because it doesn't not always contains the path.
```

As a bonus, this approach does let you force Python to use your module instead of the ones installed on the system.

Warning! I don't really know what is happening when current module is inside an `egg` file. It probably fails too.

Comment: can I get an explanation as to how this works? I've got a similar problem and I'd LOVE to force a python module DIR instead of running a search

Comment: Running Win 7 Pro 64x and Python 2.7 I get a few errors.  1) I had to add inspect to the import list.  2) The 1st value, [0], in the tuple is an empty string.  The 2nd, [1], shows the file name.  I am guessing that the first should be the path...  Any ideas?

Comment: If you are going for a subfolder, use it like this:`os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.split(inspect.getfile( inspect.currentframe() ))[0]) + "/subfolder")`
Do _NOT_ add the subfolder before `abspath` as this causes serious bugs.

Comment: @scr4ve you should use os.path.join() instead, and you are welcome to add the case (`cmd_subfolder`) directly to my answer. thanks!

Comment: for me `realpath` already generates absolute paths, thus I don't need `abspath`. Also `os.path.dirname` can be used instead of split, makeing the indexing `[0]` obsolete. The line would then be: `os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))`

Comment: `inspect.currentframe()` is a "CPython implementation detail" (https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.currentframe), so it can fail too…

Comment: What concrete cases does "__file__ fails if script is called in different ways on Windows" refer to?

Comment: does this answer requires an upgrade for python 3.4 ?

Comment: Something to keep in mind for using the `inspect` module for those who may disable the GC in their scripts: [note on reference cycles](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack).

Comment: Love the solution, but pylint doesn't.  Anyone know of a good way to make pylint shut up?

Comment: This is awful advice since the introduction of relative imports, which was well before this answer was written.

Comment: This article explains it better https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/ —- keep in mimd that the final answer may depend on the range of python versions you are targeting.

Comment: This made my pytest work out.
New issue: now mypy complains about getfile having incompatible type "Optional[FrameType]"; expected "Union[Module, Type[Any], MethodType, FunctionType, TracebackType, FrameType, CodeType, Callable[..., Any]]"

Comment: **Please do not** hack `sys.path` for this. It is **grossly unnecessary**. Many popular real-world projects span hundreds of thousands of lines of code across complex package structures without a single mention of `sys.path`. The appropriate solution is to **ensure that the package has been imported first**, and then use a simple relative import.

Answer (score 333):

Be sure that dirBar has the `__init__.py` file -- this makes a directory into a Python package.

Comment: Note that this file can be completely empty.

Comment: If dirBar's parent directory is not in `sys.path` then the presence of  `__init__.py` in the `dirBar` directory doesn't help much.

Comment: The above comment assumes that dirBar is a sub-package.

Comment: -1, adding `__init.py__` will work only when directory is already in sys.path and in my case it wasn't. Solution by "sorin" (accepted one) always works.

Comment: "when directory is already in sys.path".  While totally true, how could we guess that the directory was not in `sys.path` from the question?  Perhaps there was something omitted that we didn't see or know about?

Comment: Additional context: `__init__.py` is just a token that tells Python that you actually want to be able to use the folder with `import` (the default is "no" in order to prevent accidental namespace corruption).

Comment: Although not necessarily an ideal solution in all cases, this works very well for purposes such as module organization. Thank you!

Comment: This is by NO means the answer to the question: whether or not the initialisation file is there, this doesn't make python look into the sub-directories. How did it get hundreds of upvotes?

Comment: These comments are useful though - this is the first time I see stipulated that I need **both** `__init__.py` **and** the (parent directory of my) top directory in my `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Comment: As of Python 3.3, `__init__.py` is **not needed** to make a folder recognized as a package, and is **not relevant** to the "attempted relative import from non-package" problem.

Answer (score 265):

You could also add the subdirectory to your Python path so that it imports as a normal script.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, <path to dirFoo>)
import Bar
```

Comment: It looks that your answer does not work with relative paths, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/python-import-a-module-from-a-folder/6098238#6098238

Comment: This *does* work with relative paths -- you just need to understand that a relative path will depend on what directory you run from, which makes this a poor solution for anything other than a quick hack.

Comment: You can do something like `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/relative/path/to/module")`

Comment: or `sys.path.append(__name__ if __name__ != '__main__' else __loader__.fullname)`

Comment: Consider using `sys.path.insert(0, <path to dirFoo>)` as it will load this module before the same-name modules stored elsewhere.

Comment: **Please do not** hack `sys.path` for this. It is **grossly unnecessary**. Many popular real-world projects span hundreds of thousands of lines of code across complex package structures without a single mention of `sys.path`. The appropriate solution is to **ensure that the package has been imported first**, and then use a simple relative import.

Answer (score 118):

```
import os
import sys
lib_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, '..', '..', '..', 'lib'))
sys.path.append(lib_path)

import mymodule
```

Comment: I like this because you have the flexibility to go up a directory.

Comment: You should use `os.path.join()` instead of joining by '/', which will break in the (lame) windows.

Comment: This isn't reliable.  It depends on whatever the current working directory is, not on the directory that the script lives.

Comment: May want to only add if the path is not already in the path.
lib_path = os.path.abspath('../functions')

if lib_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(lib_path)

Comment: in reply to @jamesdlin combining a few answers: what about `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__,'..','lib'))`?

Comment: @MatthewDavis I suppose that works, but it feels really wrong to use a filename as a directory like that (and then to discard it with "..").  I'd personally prefer using `os.path.dirname(__file__)` first.

Comment: Fair point. I see the only advantage with the `'..'` approach is the succinct chaining: `os.path.join(__file__, '..', '..', '..', 'lib')` to reach multiple levels up. I suppose the most clear would be: `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..', 'lib')`, but that feel redundant. Thoughts?

Comment: **Please do not** hack `sys.path` for this. It is **grossly unnecessary**. Many popular real-world projects span hundreds of thousands of lines of code across complex package structures without a single mention of `sys.path`. The appropriate solution is to **ensure that the package has been imported first**, and then use a simple relative import.

Answer (score 109):

Just do simple things to import the .py file from a different folder.

Let's say you have a directory like:

```
lib/abc.py
```

Then just keep an empty file in lib folder as named

```
__init__.py
```

And then use

```
from lib.abc import <Your Module name>
```

Keep the `__init__.py` file in every folder of the hierarchy of the import module.

Answer (score 76):

If you structure your project this way:

```
src\
  __init__.py
  main.py
  dirFoo\
    __init__.py
    Foo.py
  dirBar\
    __init__.py
    Bar.py
```

Then from Foo.py you should be able to do:

```
import dirFoo.Foo
```

Or:

```
from dirFoo.Foo import FooObject
```

Per Tom's comment, this does require that the `src` folder is accessible either via `site_packages` or your search path. Also, as he mentions, `__init__.py` is implicitly imported when you first import a module in that package/directory. Typically `__init__.py` is simply an empty file.

Comment: Also mention that __init__.py is imported when the first module inside that package is imported. Also, your example will only work if src is in the site_packages (or in the search path)

Comment: This is the most simplest solution I was looking for. If the file to import is sure to be in one of the subdirectories, this solution is a gem.

Comment: I have tried the same thing and fail. I do not know why. ImportError: No module named customMath

Comment: Why would someone want to import Foo from within Foo.py itself. Should be from Bar.py, I guess.

Comment: `from dirFoo import Foo` to say `Foo.bla()`. If using `import dirFoo.Foo` one should use `dirFoo.Foo.bla()` - pretty ugly even without camel case.

Comment: how do you Import Bar.py from Foo.py??

Answer (score 45):

This is the relevant PEP:

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/

In particular, presuming dirFoo is a directory up from dirBar...

In dirFoo\Foo.py:

```
from .dirBar import Bar
```

Comment: it's worked for me, just added __init__.py on every folder and success to import

Comment: I think it should be `from .dirBar import Bar`.

Comment: Disturbing that I had to scroll this far for the **right** answer.

Answer (score 44):

The easiest method is to use sys.path.append().

However, you may be also interested in the [imp](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html?highlight=imp#module-imp) module.
It provides access to internal import functions.

```
# mod_name is the filename without the .py/.pyc extention
py_mod = imp.load_source(mod_name,filename_path) # Loads .py file
py_mod = imp.load_compiled(mod_name,filename_path) # Loads .pyc file
```

This can be used to load modules dynamically when you don't know a module's name.

I've used this in the past to create a plugin type interface to an application, where the user would write a script with application specific functions, and just drop thier script in a specific directory.

Also, these functions may be useful:

```
imp.find_module(name[, path])
imp.load_module(name, file, pathname, description)
```

Comment: Note that in the documentation imp.load_source and imp.load_compiled are listed as obsolete.  imp.find_module and imp.load_module are recommended instead.

Comment: @amicitas, Can you please provide any reference for that(I need it, and I am using python 2.6. I am aware what 2.7 docs say about these, but couldn't find any reference regarding 2.6)

Comment: @0xc0de You can find that statement in the docs for the imp module for both [python 2.7.3](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.3/library/imp.html) and [python 2.6.7](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.7/library/imp.html).  It looks like those functions are not even in the docs for python 3.2.

Comment: For importing source files like this in python 3.3, see [Import abitrary python source file. (Python 3.3+) - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009932/import-abitrary-python-source-file-python-3-3).  Thanks, folks for the tips here.

Answer (score 23):

The easiest way without any modification to your script is to set PYTHONPATH environment variable. Because sys.path is initialized from these locations:

1. The directory containing the input script (or the current
   directory).
2. PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same
   syntax as the shell variable PATH).
3. The installation-dependent default.

Just run:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/absolute/path/to/your/module
```

You sys.path will contains above path, as show below:

```
print sys.path

['', '/absolute/path/to/your/module', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']
```

Comment: **Please do not** hack `sys.path` for this. It is **grossly unnecessary**. Many popular real-world projects span hundreds of thousands of lines of code across complex package structures without a single mention of `sys.path`. The appropriate solution is to **ensure that the package has been imported first**, and then use a simple relative import.

Answer (score 13):

In my opinion the best choice is to put **__ init __.py** in the folder and call the file with

```
from dirBar.Bar import *
```

It is not recommended to use sys.path.append() because something might gone wrong if you use the same file name as the existing python package. I haven't test that but that will be ambiguous.

Comment: weird that `from dirBar.Bar import *` works, but not `from dirBar.Bar import Bar`. do you know why * works? what if I had multiple files in dirBar/ and wanted to grab only a few of them (using a method like the one you've posted here)?

Comment: @tester: Use `from dirBar import Bar`.

Comment: @tester it's because the `from` indicates the source, and everything after `import` is what to grab from that source. `from dirBar.Bar import Bar` means "From source, import the source itself", which doesn't make sense. 

the `*` though means, "give me everything from source"

Comment: While it's true that `sys.path` hacks are not necessary or appropriate, they are completely orthogonal to the `__init__.py` issue.

Answer (score 13):

```
from .dirBar import Bar
```

instead of:

```
from dirBar import Bar
```

just in case there could be another dirBar installed and confuse a foo.py reader.

Comment: I was not able to do this on windows. Is this on Linux?

Comment: It will work from a script importing Foo. i.e: main.py imports dirFoo.Foo.

If you are trying to run Foo.py as an script, it will Fail. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python

Answer (score 13):

For this case to import Bar.py into Foo.py, first I'd turn these folders into Python packages like so:

```
dirFoo\
    __init__.py
    Foo.py
    dirBar\
        __init__.py
        Bar.py
```

Then I would do it like this in Foo.py:

```
from .dirBar import Bar
```

If I wanted the namespacing to look like Bar.*whatever*, or

```
from . import dirBar
```

If I wanted the namespacing dirBar.Bar.*whatever*. This second case is useful if you have more modules under the dirBar package.

Answer (score 12):

### The quick-and-dirty way for Linux users

If you are just tinkering around and don't care about deployment issues, you can use a symbolic link (assuming your filesystem supports it) to make the module or package directly visible in the folder of the requesting module.

```
ln -s (path)/module_name.py
```

or

```
ln -s (path)/package_name
```

---

*Note: A "module" is any file with a .py extension and a "package" is any folder that contains the file `__init__.py` (which can be an empty file).  From a usage standpoint, modules and packages are identical -- both expose their contained "definitions and statements" as requested via the `import` command.*

See: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 5):

Add an **__init__.py** file:

```
dirFoo\
    Foo.py
    dirBar\
        __init__.py
        Bar.py
```

Then add this code to the start of Foo.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('dirBar')
import Bar
```

Comment: If `dirBar` is already a Python package (by the existence of `dirBar/__init__.py`), there is no need to append `dirBar` to `sys.path`, no? The statement `import Bar` from `Foo.py` should suffice.

Comment: **Please do not** hack `sys.path` for this. It is **grossly unnecessary**. Many popular real-world projects span hundreds of thousands of lines of code across complex package structures without a single mention of `sys.path`. The appropriate solution is to **ensure that the package has been imported first**, and then use a simple relative import.

Answer (score 3):

Relative sys.path example:

```
# /lib/my_module.py
# /src/test.py


if __name__ == '__main__' and __package__ is None:
    sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../lib')))
import my_module
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19190695/991267) answer.

Comment: **Please do not** hack `sys.path` for this. It is **grossly unnecessary**. Many popular real-world projects span hundreds of thousands of lines of code across complex package structures without a single mention of `sys.path`. The appropriate solution is to **ensure that the package has been imported first**, and then use a simple relative import.

Answer (score 3):

Well, as you mention, usually you want to have access to a folder with your modules relative to where your main script is run, so you just import them.

Solution:

I have the script in `D:/Books/MyBooks.py` and some modules (like oldies.py). I need to import from subdirectory `D:/Books/includes`:

```
import sys,site
site.addsitedir(sys.path[0] + '\\includes')
print (sys.path)  # Just verify it is there
import oldies
```

Place a `print('done')` in `oldies.py`, so you verify everything is going OK.  This way always works because by the Python definition `sys.path` as initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, `path[0]`, is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter.

If the script directory is not available (e.g. if the interpreter is invoked interactively or if the script is read from standard input), `path[0]` is the empty string, which directs Python to search modules in the current directory first. Notice that the script directory is inserted before the entries inserted as a result of `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: I had to use one forward slash instead of two backslashes (i.e. `site.addsitedir(sys.path[0]+'/includes')`) in my first simple Python program break_time.py:  [https://github.com/ltfschoen/PythonTest](https://github.com/ltfschoen/PythonTest). I use system: MacOS v10.11.5, Python 2.7.12, IDLE IDE 2.7.12, Tk 8.5.9

Comment: **Please do not** hack `sys.path` for this. It is **grossly unnecessary**. Many popular real-world projects span hundreds of thousands of lines of code across complex package structures without a single mention of `sys.path`. The appropriate solution is to **ensure that the package has been imported first**, and then use a simple relative import.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be to install the [py-require](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-require) package and then use the following in `Foo.py`

```
import require
Bar = require('./dirBar/Bar')
```

Comment: The URL actually seems to be https://pypi.org/project/require.py/, and note that it needs to be installed via Pip.

Comment: @FlashSheridan Nope, that's a different project. I deleted py-require as I was certain no one was using it, I did not think of this post though. If you still need a `require()` function, you can take a look at my Node.py project: https://github.com/nodepy/nodepy

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can use: `from Desktop.filename import something`

Example:

> given that the file is name `test.py` in directory
>   `Users/user/Desktop` , and will import everthing.

the code:

```
from Desktop.test import *
```

But make sure you make an empty file  called "`__init__.py`" in that directory

Comment: starred imports are advised against. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad

Comment: i know thats why i firstly wrote `import something` then i said to make it easier `*`  basically its not good for ram and also if 2 functions has the same name it will mass up your code

Comment: This is wrong on multiple levels. First off, it could only work if the Desktop folder is in sys.path. There is no reason that the user's code should be in any particular place relative to the desktop, and there is not *really* any reason why the user's computer should have a desktop folder at all, never mind one "in Users/user/". Aside from that, `__init__.py` files have **not been relevant** to this process since 3.3; they are **only** involved in distinguishing full packages from namespace packages, but namespace packages can be imported by the usual system just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to import a file from one level above, using the relative path.

Basically, just move the working directory up a level (or any relative location), add that to your path, then move the working directory back where it started.

```
#to import from one level above:
cwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir("..")
below_path =  os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(below_path)
os.chdir(cwd)
```

Comment: i do not understand you logic here. it's to over complicated

Comment: **Please do not** hack `sys.path` for this. It is **grossly unnecessary**. Many popular real-world projects span hundreds of thousands of lines of code across complex package structures without a single mention of `sys.path`. The appropriate solution is to **ensure that the package has been imported first**, and then use a simple relative import.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not experienced about python, so if there is any wrong in my words, just tell me. If your file hierarchy arranged like this:

```
project\
    module_1.py 
    module_2.py
```

`module_1.py` defines a function called `func_1()`, **module_2.py**:

```
from module_1 import func_1

def func_2():
    func_1()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func_2()
```

and you run `python module_2.py` in cmd, it will do run what `func_1()` defines. That's usually how we import same hierarchy files. But when you write `from .module_1 import func_1` in `module_2.py`, python interpreter will say `No module named '__main__.module_1'; '__main__' is not a package`. So to fix this, we just keep the change we just make, and move both of the module to a package, and make a third module as a caller to run `module_2.py`.

```
project\
    package_1\
        module_1.py
        module_2.py
    main.py
```

**main.py**:

```
from package_1.module_2 import func_2

def func_3():
    func_2()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func_3()
```

But the reason we add a `.` before `module_1` in `module_2.py` is that if we don't do that and run `main.py`, python interpreter will say `No module named 'module_1'`, that's a little tricky, `module_1.py` is right beside `module_2.py`. Now I let `func_1()` in `module_1.py` do something:

```
def func_1():
    print(__name__)
```

that `__name__` records who calls func_1. Now we keep the `.` before `module_1` , run `main.py`, it will print `package_1.module_1`, not `module_1`. It indicates that the one who calls `func_1()` is at the same hierarchy as `main.py`, the `.` imply that `module_1` is at the same hierarchy as `module_2.py` itself. So if there isn't a dot, `main.py` will recognize `module_1` at the same hierarchy as itself, it can recognize `package_1`, but not what "under" it.

Now let's make it a bit complicated. You have a `config.ini` and a module defines a function to read it at the same hierarchy as 'main.py'.

```
project\
    package_1\
        module_1.py
        module_2.py
    config.py
    config.ini
    main.py
```

And for some unavoidable reason, you have to call it with `module_2.py`, so it has to import from upper hierarchy.**module_2.py**:

```
 import ..config
 pass
```

Two dots means import from upper hierarchy (three dots access upper than upper,and so on). Now we run `main.py`, the interpreter will say:`ValueError:attempted relative import beyond top-level package`. The "top-level package" at here is `main.py`. Just because `config.py` is beside `main.py`, they are at same hierarchy, `config.py` isn't "under" `main.py`, or it isn't "leaded" by `main.py`, so it is beyond `main.py`. To fix this, the simplest way is:

```
project\
    package_1\
        module_1.py
        module_2.py
    config.py
    config.ini
main.py
```

I think that is coincide with the principle of arrange project file hierarchy, you should arrange modules with different function in different folders, and just leave a top caller in the outside, and you can import how ever you want.

Answer (score -4):

This also works, and is much simpler than anything with the `sys` module:

```
with open("C:/yourpath/foobar.py") as f:
    eval(f.read())
```

Comment: If OP was going to hardcode a path, they could just insert that path into the PYTHONPATH anyway. I think the point is doing so in a manner that does not hardcode a path since it would break anywhere else.

Answer (score -18):

Call me overly cautious, but I like to make mine more portable because it's unsafe to assume that files will always be in the same place on every computer. Personally I have the code look up the file path first. I use Linux so mine would look like this:

```
import os, sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
try:
    path = Popen("find / -name 'file' -type f", shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout.read().splitlines()[0]
    if not sys.path.__contains__(path):
        sys.path.append(path)
except IndexError:
    raise RuntimeError("You must have FILE to run this program!")
```

That is of course unless you plan to package these together. But if that's the case you don't really need two separate files anyway.

Comment: Files will *always* be in the same place on every computer, given a relative path.

Comment: **Please do not** hack `sys.path` for this. It is **grossly unnecessary**. Many popular real-world projects span hundreds of thousands of lines of code across complex package structures without a single mention of `sys.path`. The appropriate solution is to **ensure that the package has been imported first**, and then use a simple relative import.